# C# compiler option ErrorLog how to use project name or assmeblyname as log file name in msbuild or dotnet cli

Tags: c#, msbuild, dotnet-cli, compiler-options, dotnet-sdk

There is option in c# compiler for getting code analysis log using errorlog option,
refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/errors-warnings

if we give just string it works but $(ProjectName) or $(AssemblyName) does not work it treat it as string instead project property

msbuild mysolution.sln /property:ErrorLog=$(AssemblyName).sarif

above command generate log file as $(AssemblyName).sarif instead MyProject.sarif

How to correctly use errolog switch to get project name prepended to log file name string.

Comment: `$(AssemblyName)` is a reference to an MSBuild property. References to properties on the command line will not be recognized. MSBuild doesn't evaluate the values in the `/property` switch for property references.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command line `/property` switch doesn't evaluate the values for property references. A value like `$(AssemblyName).sarif` will be taken as a literal. The property reference will not be expanded.

Instead create a [`Directory.Build.props` file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-by-directory?view=vs-2022) in the solution folder (or a folder that contains all the project folders) with the following content:

```xml
<Project>
 <PropertyGroup>
   <ErrorLog>$(AssemblyName).sarif</ErrorLog>
 </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```